# Is it possible to plot multiple matplotlib.pyplots into one plot so they all overlap in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a function that returns a matplotlib.pyplot. I am putting this in a loop.
SO at the end I want all my plots to be in one plot overlapping or combined with each other.

for example:

```
def plotting_func():
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    ....
    ....
    .... // some calculations
    ....
    plt.plot()
    return plt // returns matplotlib.pyplot

def plotter():
    import matplotlib.pyplot as y
    for i in range(100):
       y = plotting_func()
       y.plot()
    y.savefig() // should have all combined 100 plots
```

is there any way to do this in Python or a better way to do it?

Comment: Well, you can't return "a matplotlib.pyplot". You're just returning a reference to the pyplot library.  The way your function seem to look now, you could just leave out `y.plot()` and replace `y.savefig()` with `plt.savefig()`. You can't "save" plots to be drawn later. While you don't explicitly erase the plot nor create a new plot nor call `plt.show()`, matplotlib will keep adding stuff to the "current" plot.

Comment: As JohanC said, it doesn't make sense to return a "pyplot" object. You could instead return a figure object, sand save them individually using `savefig`

Comment: @JohanC I tried that out. I removed y.plot() and replace y.savefig() with plt.savefig() and it still just plots the 100th graph and not all 100 combined. Can you help clarify what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @falafelocelot Thanks, but I need to save them as one figure with all plots combined so I dont think saving them individually would work. But please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Could you create a reproducible example, just drawing two simple plots?  Note that your example code doesn't give a parameter to `plotting_func()` which unless you are using randomness would always create the same plot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example (using randomness, as the test code doesn't get an input parameter). Of course, you can just put the import outside the functions. You could use transparency (`alpha`) if you'd plot many simulations on top of each other.

```
def plotting_func():
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    x = np.arange(100)
    y = np.random.randn(100).cumsum()
    plt.plot(x, y)

def plotter():
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    for i in range(100):
       plotting_func()
    plt.savefig('plot_100.png')

plotter()
```

[image: 100 plots on top of each other]